# no login in 17.10 (Radeon HD 7470)

Tags: drivers, updates, radeon, amd-graphics, 17.10

I have recently updated to 17.10. All went well until Friday when I didn't get a login.
Yesterday (Oct 28) I installed the current 17.10 Live version which worked - until I got an update for this one, too. Today again no login.
Now I can login with the boot option nomodeset, and I think the problem lies with the graphics drivers. However I don't know which driver to use and where to get it. The versions I found were mostly valid for up to Ubuntu 16.

```
# lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]    Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235/310 OEM]
```

Is there any generic driver I could use? I don't need extra performance, but using a better screen resolution than 800x600 would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My graphics is working again. 
Out of sheer despair I followed an advice found somewhere to switch from wayland to xorg (I've never heard of wayland):
In /etc/gdm3/custom.conf I uncommented `WaylandEnable=false`.

That did it. I'm back to a screen resolution of 1680x1050 which is A LOT better than 800x600!

I hope this survives the next update ;-)